# How do I facilitate easy year-to-year navigation using react-datepicker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-datepicker

I was thinking of having some double arrows that allow year scrolling similar to the month scrolling ones. Other ideas on how to reach the main goals are more than welcome.

GitHub link:
https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker

Answer (score 5):

You can look [this example](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-monthyear-dropdown). You need to pass `showMonthDropdown` and `showYearDropdown` for the DatePicker to display select dropdowns for year and month.

Answer (score 0):

do you want something like this.

[image: react-datepicker]

just add this code to your react calendar :

```
dateFormatCalendar="YYYY"
```

Comment: Well sort of. I think you were hoping this will make the arrows change the year but that's not what happens the arrows still change the month.

I want to be able to change both month and year using the calendar with easy for the user.

Comment: To make it clear, I would want something like http://projekty.wojtekmaj.pl/react-date-picker/ (notice the double arrows that allow changing years). An alternative solution which I like for easy date of birth selection can be found here https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ (see ViewMode)